# Streamlining an object, can I create this data as an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object containing some data. The first dimension runs from 1-12 representing months of the year. Within that, I have certain ID's which are "true" for that month:

```
var monthData = {
   1: { 219: true, 474: true },
   2: { 219: true, 391: true },
   3: { 219: true },
   ...
};
```

To use this data, I search for the `month` (value 1-12) and then the `ID` within that month (e.g 391). If the `ID` is present within that month then I `return true;`

```
return !!monthData[month][ID];
```

However when looking at the full data I have, it seems there is a lot of repetition. I'm repeating `219: true` for example in every month. I'm also repeating `true` after every ID - where really just the presence of the `ID` makes it true, so I feel like this could be refined.

Could I store this as array data instead? Is there an easy way to iterate through this and return the data as I want?

Full function below:

```
findIDByMonth : function (month,ID) {
                var monthData = {
                    1: { 219: true, 474: true },
                    2: { 219: true, 474: true },
                    3: { 219: true, 474: true },
                    4: { 219: true, 296: true, 391: true, 474: true, 578: true, 917: true, 987: true, 1036: true },
                    5: { 219: true, 296: true, 391: true, 474: true, 578: true, 917: true, 987: true, 1036: true },
                    6: { 219: true, 391: true, 474: true, 578: true, 834: true, 917: true, 987: true, 1036: true },
                    7: { 219: true, 251: true, 391: true, 474: true, 578: true, 834: true, 917: true, 987: true, 1036: true },
                    8: { 219: true, 251: true, 391: true, 474: true, 526: true, 578: true, 834: true, 917: true, 987: true, 1036: true, 1092: true },
                    9: { 219: true, 251: true, 296: true, 391: true, 474: true, 526: true, 578: true, 897: true, 917: true, 987: true, 1036: true, 1092: true },
                    10: { 219: true, 251: true, 391: true, 474: true, 526: true, 578: true, 897: true, 917: true, 987: true, 1036: true, 1092: true },
                    11: { 219: true, 474: true, 987: true, 1036: true },
                    12: { 219: true, 474: true }
                };
                return !!monthData[month][ID];
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put something like this in your function. I think that an array could be a good choice for readability as you mentioned. I kept your outer object untouched because it doesn't appear to need to be changed to an array as it wouldn't reduce your length of code by much and it is more clear which month you are selecting.

```
var monthData = {
   1: [219, 474],
   2: [219, 391],
   ...
};

return !!monthData[month].includes(ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store all the data as an array of arrays and then use `indexOf()` to search the data.

```
function findIDByMonth(month,ID) {
    var monthData = [
        [219, 474],
        [219, 474],
        [219, 474],
        [219, 296, 391, 474, 578, 917, 987, 1036],
        [219, 296, 391, 474, 578, 917, 987, 1036],
        [219, 391, 474, 578, 834, 917, 987, 1036],
        [219, 251, 391, 474, 578, 834, 917, 987, 1036],
        [219, 251, 391, 474, 526, 578, 834, 917, 987, 1036, 1092],
        [219, 251, 296, 391, 474, 526, 578, 897, 917, 987, 1036, 1092],
        [219, 251, 391, 474, 526, 578, 897, 917, 987, 1036, 1092],
        [219, 474, 987, 1036],
        [219, 474]];

    return monthData[month - 1].indexOf(ID) !== -1;
}
```

As for the repetition of IDs within the months, unless it's static data then there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: @Aschab it's both.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: You were right I was wrong, deleted the comment, sry :P

Comment: @Aschab No worries  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
findIDByMonth : function (month,ID) {
                var monthData = [
                    [ 219, 474 ],
                    [ 219, 474 ],
                    [ 219, 474 ],
                    [ 219, 296, 391, 474, 578, 917, 987, 1036 ],
                    [ 219, 296, 391, 474, 578, 917, 987, 1036 ],
                    [ 219, 391, 474, 578, 834, 917, 987, 1036 ],
                    [ 219, 251, 391, 474, 578, 834, 917, 987, 1036 ],
                    [ 219, 251, 391, 474, 526, 578, 834, 917, 987, 1036, 1092 ],
                    [ 219, 251, 296, 391, 474, 526, 578, 897, 917, 987, 1036, 1092 ],
                    [ 219, 251, 391, 474, 526, 578, 897, 917, 987, 1036, 1092 ],
                    [ 219, 474, 987, 1036 ],
                    [ 219, 474 ]
                ];
                return monthData[month-1].includes(ID);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you are looking for when you say you want to store your data as array.

If you want to completely flatten your data you can create an array of strings instead, in the form `month-id`, so it'd become something like this:

```
var monthData=["1-219", "1-474", "2-219", "2-474"....];
```

then you can check if the array contains the month-id combination

```
return monthData.includes(month+"-"+ID);
```

If your purpose is to check for the existance of a specific item then your original representation is the best because accessing an object's property is done in constant time while iterating an array is more expensive (linear time, often optimized though), so even though it's kinda ugly yours is the most efficient representation for your data if your purpose is to check the existance of a specific id